# MIcrosoft Feedback Client can't connect to Team Foundation Server

Tags: azure-devops

I have a problem with the `MIcrosoft Feedback Client`, and in general the `Request feedback` option in VSTS.

If I try to open a request from the notification email, the Feedback Client displays the following error:

> Cannot connect to Team Foundation Server. Verify the network connection and try again.

However, if I simply launch it as an application, I got a popup first, where I need to pick the server, the team project collection and finally the project I'd like to connect to (it doesn't ask for login). This works just fine and the submitted feedback is displayed in VSTS, it can be queried, etc.

I removed all cookies and cleared browser cache from all browsers I use, also I checked if there's a false entry in `Windows Credential Manager`.

Any suggestions what I should try next?

**update**
We use `Feedback Client for Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015` downloaded from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads#d-feedback-client)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the account you use have the permission to access to the project and view the work items.

Feedback client use the credentials stored in Team Explorer. Try to delete the stored credentials from "Visual Studio -> Team -> Manage Connections -> Manage Connections -> Servers -> Remove" and then launch Feedback Client from email. A sign in dialog will pop up after this and you can enter your credential in it.

If it still does not work, clean all the TFS cache from "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache" folder.

And also, check the link in the email to make sure it is correct. The link should like following:

```
mfbclients://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/p:ProjectName?rid=FeedbackID
```

Comment: Ah, that's it. The link in the email is mfbclient://, when I changed it by hand to mfbclients://, it worked immeditately

Answer (score 0):

What version of the TFS Client are you using 2012, 2013 or 2015? I ran into a similar issue when we were using this on premise and I had to bump down to a lower version of the TFS Feedback Client.

Here is the TFS 2015 client.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40768

I just tested mine to VSTS and it worked as expected.